# Evaluating $\int_{a}^{b}e^{-x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I know how to evaluate the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x$, but how would you evaluate the same integral on some finite interval $[a,b]$ without the use of Taylor series?

Comment: You can't find a nice primitive of $e^{-x^2}$, you can only approximate the integral with series for instance.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use numerical integration methods (e.g., Simpson's rule).

Comment: You can use a calculator

Answer (score 2):

Remembering that
$$\int e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\frac{ \sqrt{\pi }}{2} \text{erf}(x)$$
$$\int_a^b e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\frac{ \sqrt{\pi }}{2}\left( \text{erf}(b) - \text{erf}(a)\right)$$ which is simple to compute ... if you can compute the value of the error function.

If you cannot, then you need some approximation. A few years ago,  a quite good approximation has been proposed by Sergei Winitzki 
$$\text{erf}(x)\approx \text{sgn}(x) \sqrt{1 - \exp\left(-x^2\frac{\frac{4}{\pi} + ax^2}{1 + ax^2}\right)}\qquad a = \frac{8(\pi - 3)}{3\pi(4 - \pi)}$$